# Android Espresso: why my tests don't pass in multi-module project?

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing, multi-module

I started to split my single module project into many modules. Before this my tests passed. But now I have an error:

androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (is displayed on the screen to the user and with id: com.ecwid.android:id/some_id)

I moved some base custom views to the "general" module which shared with all other modules and all these views in the tests don't pass with a no ids matching.I have an "app" module which has all my tests. Maybe I wrote my dependencies in gradle badly?
It's like:

```
androidTestImplementation project(':general')
```

Also the Espresso dependencies were added to all modules.

Comment: It is hard to help you based on this description. Maybe you could provide some more code? If you can extract some minimal use case for the test, layout and activity/fragment being tested, we could help you better.

Comment: @ferini ok, I'll edit this later, I don't have much time

Comment: General tip: Most Android tests should use `@UiThreadTest` and skip the `onView()` DSL. Tests should treat view objects like objects; not run in a separate thread for no reason.

Comment: You can follow the sample Espresso test in this repo: https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be testImplementation instead of androidTestImplementation?